# How to use cy.contains for a common method in cypress

Tags: cypress

I wanted to use a search box and enter an input text. Multiple search boxes exist in the different left panels. Once I click any link from the left panel, it takes me to a specific page that contains a search box. How to write one common search box identifier and use it everywhere

Following are search box identifiers on various pages.

```
data-testid="leftpanel1-searchInput"
data-testid="leftpanel2-searchInput"
data-testid="leftpanel3-searchInput"
```

Answer (score 1):

Cypress uses CSS selectors, and your answer is available right in the Cypress documentation [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get#Find-the-element-with-id-that-ends-with-remote)

Though below works with both `cy.contains()` and `cy.get()`, you no need to use `contains`. Simply put,  `cy.get('[data-testid$=-searchInput]');`

Answer (score 1):

`[data-testid*='leftpanel1']` this will select all elements or you can say it's common search box identifier